# How do I solve a determinant in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math, determinants

As a simple example, let's say you have this matrix:

```
M = [omega 1;
     2     omega];
```

and you need to solve for the values of `omega` that satisfy the condition `det M = 0`.
How do you do this in MATLAB?

It is surely something simple, but I haven't found the function yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the general case where your matrix could be anything, you would want to create a symbolic representation of your matrix, compute the determinant, and solve for the variable of interest. You can do this using, respectively, the functions [SYM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/sym.html), [DET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/det.html), and [SOLVE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html) from the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/):

```
>> A = sym('[w 1; 2 w]');  % Create symbolic matrix
>> solve(det(A),'w')       % Solve the equation 'det(A) = 0' for 'w'

ans =

  2^(1/2)
 -2^(1/2)

>> double(ans)             % Convert the symbolic expression to a double

ans =

    1.4142
   -1.4142
```

There are also different ways to create the initial matrix `A`. Above, I did it with one string expression. However, I could instead use [SYMS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/syms.html) to define `w` as a symbolic variable, then construct a matrix as you normally would in MATLAB:

```
syms w
A = [w 1; 2 w];
```

and now `A` is a symbolic matrix just as it was in the first example.

Comment: I didn't know about the symbolic matrices... that's pretty cool. You've got my vote.

Comment: steven <-- what he said. And exactly something I was hoping for ... ftw.

Comment: Ugh, another matlabism... I am not entirely happy with this. I don't like that sym takes in a string rather than a matrix. That could cause some frustration down the road.

Comment: @steven: I addressed your concern somewhat with the recent edit to my answer. Also, if you are passing a numeric matrix to SYM, you don't need to pass it as a string. For example: `A = sym([1 1; 2 2])`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the symbolic toolbox, then use the [sympoly](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9577) toolbox, found on the file exchange.

```
sympoly omega
roots(det([omega 1;2 omega]))
ans =
      -1.4142
       1.4142
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the determinate is:
om * om - 1*2 = 0

So you would get: om*om = 2

The formal definition is: [a b ; c d] = a*d - b*c

I would look into simplifying the determinate, and finding a solver to solve for the unknowns.

Comment: Yes, obviously. But the above given is just an example. I don't have such a trivial case in my problem.